# How to get the whole json with the result reflected after filter by string using JsonPath

Tags: json, jsonpath, jayway

Can I get the whole json with the result reflected after filter by string using JsonPath?

- Before JSON

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            } 
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

- After JSON  (I want this result)

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            }       
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

Filter by string for book is done through '$..book[?(@.author =~ /.*REES/i)]'

but can you tell me to get the whole JSON reflected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this using JSONPath; while you want to select the outer-most item based on inner items property, you do not want to retrieve the outer item as a whole. That does not work.

Selecting the outer item can be done like this

```
$..store[?(@.book[0].author =~ /.*REES/i)]
```

but this will also return the book at position 2, i.e. index 1.

It sounds like you actually need a JSON transformation like [Jolt](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt).

For instance, Jolt's remove transformer would allow you to to remove the second book like this:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "store": {
        "book": {
          "array": {
            "1": "" //remove book at position 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Try it online with your own input [here](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/).

Comment: JSONPath alone cannot do it..! I'll look for the Jolt . Thanks for the answer!